# Google Spreadsheets: How to order column when value is introduced with Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, bots

The difference between the posts I have seen is that I don't change the cell values by myself. I have a program that changes these values.

So... the `onEdit` function is not triggered when the cell value changes

What I have right now is:

```
SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A1:D900";
SORT_ORDER = [
  {column: 1, ascending: true}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order 
];

function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
```

The only problem as I told before is that since I am not changing the value directly, the `onEdit` function doesn't start. Is there any other function that I should?

Thanks!

Comment: onEdit is only triggered by manual edits. I'd try just putting your sort on a 30 or 60 minute timed trigger.

Comment: Give that `I have a program that changes these`, would it not be possible to integrate the "sort" function within *that* program directly? I'm assuming you mean to say that another apps script is updating the sheet and so the `onEdit` doesn't kick in.

Comment: As @SourabhChoraria said, I think the best option would be to make the program that changes values to also sort the columns by itself. Is there a reason you cannot do this?

Comment: I am using Python. I searched a lot but I don't see any post on how to do it... Every sorts the list inside the scripts of Google Sheets

Comment: So, if you are using Sheets API, you can use spreadsheets.batchUpdate to sort the columns, as in this example (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/data#sort_a_range_with_multiple_sorting_specifications).